# Cannot extract Count from AddThis Object

Tags: javascript, wordpress, addthis

I'm trying to set up a WordPress template that will scan through the posts on the site, and display the number of shares.

I'm using AddThis, I've commented out my ID.

I cannot seem to extract the social count from the object.

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script>
<script>
var addthis_config = {
 pubid: 'ra-4f563d934bfbf729'
}
</script>

<?php

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

 echo "<table class='table'>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>Title</th>";
 echo "<th>Facebook</th>";
 echo "<th>Twitter</th>";
 echo "<th>Reddit</th>";
 echo "<th>Delicious</th>";
 echo "<th>Linkedin</th>";
 echo "</tr>";

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<tr class="id-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">

  <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>

  <td class="facebook">
    <a class="addthis_counter_facebook"></a>
  </td>

  <td class="twitter">
    <script>
      addthis.sharecounters.getShareCounts({service: ['twitter'], countUrl: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>'}, function(obj) {
        console.log(obj.count);
      });
    </script>
  </td>

  <td class="reddit">
    <script>
      addthis.sharecounters.getShareCounts({service: ['reddit'], countUrl: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>'}, function(obj) {
        console.log(obj)
      });
    </script>
  </td>

  <td class="delicious">
    <script>
      addthis.sharecounters.getShareCounts({service: ['delicious'], countUrl: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>'}, function(obj) {
        console.log(obj)
      });
    </script>
  </td>

  <td class="linkedin">
    <script>
      addthis.sharecounters.getShareCounts({service: ['linkedin'], countUrl: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>'}, function(obj) {
        console.log(obj)
      });
    </script>
  </td>

</tr>

<?php

endwhile; wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata();

 echo "</table>";

endif;

 get_footer();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I used...

```
<script>
    addthis.sharecounters.getShareCounts({service: ['twitter'], countUrl: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>'}, function(obj) {
      $count = obj[0].count;
      $('tr.id-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> .twitter').text( $count );
    });
  </script>
  <td class="twitter"></td>
```